# Sharing link of a page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am sharing link of an event from profile of user, the page of event is dynamic, When user click on share to Facebook, I get ID of event and store it to Session variable, and I am using this session variable in events page to describe the: og tags. But my: og tags are not showing the data.
Here is my Code:

```
    function post(id) {
        document.cookie = "eventID = "+id;
        <?php $_SESSION['EVENT_ID'] = $_COOKIE['eventID']; ?>;
        FB.ui({
               method: 'share',
               href: "mywebsiteURL/events.php"
           }
     }
//Here is the head of my events.php
    $col = 'events.*,status.name as statusName,mosque_reg.name as mosque';
    $table = "events,status,mosque_reg";
    $where = "events.id = '".$obj->verifyint($_SESSION['EVENT_ID'])."' AND events.status_id = status.id 
    AND events.inserted_by = mosque_reg.inserted_by"; 
    $ticket = $obj->read_specific_event($col,$table,$where);
    if($ticket->num_rows>0)
    {
     $issue = $ticket->fetch_assoc();
     $pic ="https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/mosque/portal/images/events/".$issue['photo'];
     $contactName = $issue['contactPerson'];
     $contact = $issue['contactNumber'];
     $description = $issue['description'];
     $topic = $issue['topic'];
  }
  ?>
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="258374655358948" />
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="The Global Muslim"/>
   <link property="og:url"           content="https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/events.php?id=<?php echo 
   $_SESSION['EVENT_ID']; ?>"/>
   <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
   <meta property="og:title"         content="Event Name:<?php echo $topic; ?>" />
   <meta property="og:description"   content="New event is held at Mosque <?php echo 
   $issue['mosque']."\n."." Description: ".$description ?>" />
   <meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $pic; ?>" />
```

Comment: *throws holy water at code*

Comment: have you used `session_start()` ?

Comment: yes, its in my connection file, the session variable is working fine.

Comment: _“the session variable is working fine”_ - no, it is not. It is working fine _for you_, because your browser has the session ID stored in a cookie. When the Facebook scraper requests your URL to fetch the meta data, it does not have that session ID. So PHP will start a new, empty session, beause no session ID was passed with this request. Sessions are the wrong thing for what you want to achieve here in the first place, you need to pass whatever info you need to pass, in the shared URL itself.

Comment: Please work on making your code more readable in the future.
This alone can help you solve a lot of bugs.

Comment: can you suggest me any site for coding style ?

Comment: Google PSR-2 @SybghatallahMarwat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by opening the URL of page inside  and their i used GET method to display event information in :og tags.